# Creating dashboards in tableau

Tags: excel, tableau-api

I need to combine the energy consumption every month in my company from various sources. I do the calculations in the excel sheets which I receive every month. How do i combine all the sheets and make a dashboard and also update the dashboard every month automatically once the excel is updated?
Which is the best form of tableau to use(Public,desktop or server)? 
What exactly is the difference among the three? 
Are the excel sheets a good data source in tableau?

Answer (score 3):

You are asking a lot of questions which should probably be raised separately, but I will try to answer some of them anyway since they all relate to the same use case.

**1. How do I combine and make a dashboard**

Since Tableau 9.3 you are able to use Union. This will combine all your excel files into a single source of data you can use. I think your data sources should however have the same structure. Meaning the sheets containing information should have the same columns.
You can dynamically and automatically do this using wildcard search. This way it will try and add all files that for example are located in the same folder.
More information on this [here](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/union.html).

From the moment you have at least one file as a data source you can start creating a dashboard.

**2. Which is the best form of Tableau**

I don't think you truly understand the difference between the Tableau applications you mention.
You will need **Tableau Dashboard** to actually create a dashboard.

If you want to be able to share this dashboard through the web you will need either **Tableau Server**, **Tableau Public** or **Tableau Online**. Everything published on Tableau public will be publicly available. So if your data is considered restricted, sensitive or should not be shared outside your company you should not consider this.
Tableau server on the other hand is server software you can install on a local host which allows you to publish your dashboards and sheets so people with a Tableau server license can access it through a web interface.
Then there is **Tableau Online** which offers almost the same except that Tableau will take care of the hosting. This is the SaaS solution for making your dashboards available online.
Lastly there is **Tableau Reader** which is a free desktop application that is able to open your Tableau workbooks, but cannot modify them and has limited access to external data sources.

**3. Is Excel a good data source**

This really depends on your use case and is probably opinion based. Since the possibility of union and the ability to automatically bring in and update data I think Excel files can be a useful resource. What you need to consider is where the Excel files are stored, how you will connect to them and how many users will need to access them. If other users can easily modify the Excel file and create errors this is another downside of using them as a source.
When you publish your dashboard on e.g. Tableau Server and you want the dashboard to automatically change there as well, the Excel file needs to be accessible from there as well and should not be included in the dashboard. If you feel like none of the above is an issue then at the moment Excel is great for you.